# How to create uialertcontroller in global swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to create `uialertcontroller` in `Config.swift` file as follow.

```
static func showAlertMessage(titleStr:String, messageStr:String) -> Void {
    let window : UIWindow?
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleStr, message: messageStr, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    self.window!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

problem is I've found problem in `self.window!.`

> Type 'Config' has no member 'window'

Please let me know how to solve that issue.

Comment: I would add another argument of type view controller and present the alert using that controller.

Comment: you should request the presenter as parameter as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`self.window` would mean that there's a `window` object in this class, and it's not the case.

You would need to use your `let window : UIWindow?` with `window?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`, but this won't help, since this window does not actually represent any existing window, and it's not a view controller anyway.

So I suggest you pass the actual view controller you'll be using to the method:

```
static func showAlertMessage(vc: UIViewController, titleStr:String, messageStr:String) -> Void {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleStr, message: messageStr, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    vc.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and you call it from a class where a UIViewController object is available.

Comment: Update Xcode. Clean your project. Check that UIKit is imported.

Answer (score 37):

**swift**

Here's what I used, this is the same as @penatheboss answered, just add the ability of adding actions and handlers.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func popupAlert(title: String?, message: String?, actionTitles:[String?], actions:[((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?]) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        for (index, title) in actionTitles.enumerated() {
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default, handler: actions[index])
            alert.addAction(action)
        }
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Just make sure `actionTitles` and `actions` array the same count. Pass **nil** if you don't need any action handler closure.

```
self.popupAlert(title: "Title", message: " Oops, xxxx ", actionTitles: ["Option1","Option2","Option3"], actions:[{action1 in

},{action2 in

}, nil])
```

**Objective C**:

Add the category for `UIViewController`

**UIViewController+PopAlert.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (UIViewControllerCategory)
- (void) popAlertWithTitle: (NSString*) title message: (NSString*) message actionTitles:(NSArray *) actionTitles actions:(NSArray*)actions;
@end
```

**UIViewController+PopAlert.m**

```
#import "UIViewController+PopAlert.h"

@implementation UIViewController (UIViewControllerCategory)
- (void) popAlertWithTitle: (NSString*) title message: (NSString*) message actionTitles:(NSArray *) actionTitles actions:(NSArray*)actions {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [actionTitles enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:obj style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:actions[idx]];
        [alert addAction:action];
    }];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

**Usage**:

```
#import UIViewController+PopAlert.h
```

...

```
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    NSArray *actions = @[^(){NSLog(@"I am action1");}, ^(){NSLog(@"I am action2");}];
    [self popAlertWithTitle:@"I am title" message:@"good" actionTitles:@[@"good1", @"good2"] actions:actions];
```

Comment: Great solution! placed this in a Globals.swift and I'm able to call it from any view controller. +1

Comment: thanks,  I add editable action styles too, 
    `func popupAlert(title: String?, message: String?, actionTitles:[String?], actionStyles:[Int?], actions:[((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?]) {}`

     `self.popupAlert(title: "Title", message: " Oops, xxxx ",
     actionTitles: ["Option1","Option2","Option3"],
    actionsStyles:[UIAlertActionStyle.destructive.rawValue,UIAlertActionStyle.default.rawValue,,UIAlertActionStyle.default.rawValue]` .....

Comment: Great Solution and question How to change the style?

Comment: @JUL2791You mean ```UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default``` or ```preferredStyle: .alert```? Then just change style from ```.alert``` to ```actionSheet```; same as it, you can change ```UIAlertAction``` style from ```.default``` to other options.

Comment: Could you also paste the same snippet for obj-c? I couldn't figure out how to pass the handlers and titles as variable paramters

Comment: @Uma You can make it by category or subclass ```UIViewController```, seem my edit, I only provide you the category way. Hope it helps.

Comment: @WilliamHu Thank you very much.!!

Comment: that's what i was looking for.

Comment: @WilliamHu This code works for me, thank you so much

Answer (score 9):

### Details

- Swift 5.1, Xcode 11.3.1

#### Global UIAlertController With UIViewController Extension

```
extension UIViewController{

    // Global Alert
    // Define Your number of buttons, styles and completion
    public func openAlert(title: String,
                          message: String,
                          alertStyle:UIAlertController.Style,
                          actionTitles:[String],
                          actionStyles:[UIAlertAction.Style],
                          actions: [((UIAlertAction) -> Void)]){

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: alertStyle)
        for(index, indexTitle) in actionTitles.enumerated(){
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: indexTitle, style: actionStyles[index], handler: actions[index])
            alertController.addAction(action)
        }
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

### Usage

#### Alert

```
self.openAlert(title: "alert",
                      message: "add your message",
                      alertStyle: .alert,
                      actionTitles: ["Okay", "Cancel"],
                      actionStyles: [.default, .cancel],
                      actions: [
                          {_ in
                               print("okay click")
                          },
                          {_ in
                               print("cancel click")
                          }
                     ])
```

#### ActionSheet

```
self.openAlert(title: "actionsheet",
                  message: "add your message",
                  alertStyle: .actionSheet,
                  actionTitles: ["Okay", "Cancel"],
                  actionStyles: [.default, .cancel],
                  actions: [
                      {_ in
                           print("okay click")
                      },
                      {_ in
                           print("cancel click")
                      }
                 ])
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating an extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlertMessage(titleStr:String, messageStr:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleStr, message: messageStr, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
       self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add this line also...        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

Comment: @kishan94 that is dependent on the programmers choices of what she/he wants to do with the alert

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, please add below code in `AppDelegate.swift` file.

```
 static func showAlertView(vc : UIViewController, titleString : String , messageString: String) ->()
    {
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: titleString, message: messageString, preferredStyle: .alert)

        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .cancel) { (alert) in
            vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alertView.addAction(alertAction)
        vc.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

and call **`showAlertView`** method from any viewcontroller

```
AppDelegate.showAlertView(vc: self, titleString: "testTitle", messageString: "test msg")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am suggest you write this code, but if you really need, try this:

```
static func showAlertMessage(titleStr:String, messageStr:String) -> Void {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleStr, message: messageStr, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    if let viewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.rootViewController as UIViewController? {
        viewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

At least it won't break down.

@Eric D better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I created a alerMessage class .I can call any where in my application

```
//Common Alert Message Class 

class AlertMessage {

internal static var alertMessageController:UIAlertController!

internal static func disPlayAlertMessage(titleMessage:String, alertMsg:String){


    AlertMessage.alertMessageController = UIAlertController(title: titleMessage, message:
        alertMsg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    AlertMessage.alertMessageController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
    if let controller = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
        controller.presentViewController(AlertMessage.alertMessageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(AlertMessage.alertMessageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    return

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below GIT Example

https://github.com/amilaim/CommonAlertView

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  CommonAlertView
//
//  Created by Amila Munasinghe on 4/25/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Developer Insight. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,AlertViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var AlertViewResultTextOutlet: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func ShowAlertAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let alert = AlertViewController.sharedInstance
    alert.delegate = self
    alert.SubmitAlertView(viewController: self,title: "Developer Insight", message: "Please enter any text value")

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func SubmitAlertViewResult(textValue : String) {

    AlertViewResultTextOutlet.text = textValue

 } 
}
```

Common UIAlertViewController Implementation

```
import UIKit

protocol AlertViewControllerDelegate {
func SubmitAlertViewResult(textValue : String)
 }

class AlertViewController {

static let sharedInstance = AlertViewController()

private init(){}

var delegate : AlertViewControllerDelegate?

func SubmitAlertView(viewController : UIViewController,title : String, message : String){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
                                  message: message,
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)

    // Submit button
    let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        // Get 1st TextField's text
        let textField = alert.textFields![0]

        if(textField.text != "")
        {
            self.delegate?.SubmitAlertViewResult(textValue: textField.text!)
        }

    })

    // Cancel button
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in })


    // Add 1 textField and cutomize it
    alert.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in
        textField.keyboardAppearance = .dark
        textField.keyboardType = .default
        textField.autocorrectionType = .default
        textField.placeholder = "enter any text value"
        textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

    }

    // Add action buttons and present the Alert
    alert.addAction(submitAction)
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I'm using based on the solution by @William Hu:

```
func popup(caller:UIViewController, style:UIAlertControllerStyle? = UIAlertControllerStyle.alert,
        title:String, message:String, buttonTexts:[String], buttonStyles:([UIAlertActionStyle?])? = nil,
        handlers:[((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?], animated:Bool? = nil, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style!)
    for i in 0..<buttonTexts.count {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTexts[i],
            style: (buttonStyles == nil || i >= buttonStyles!.count || buttonStyles![i] == nil ?
                UIAlertActionStyle.default : buttonStyles![i]!),
            handler: (i >= handlers.count || handlers[i] == nil ? nil : handlers[i]!)))
    }
    caller.present(alert, animated: animated != nil ? animated! : true, completion: completion)
}
```

1. Single function gives `Alert` by default and can optionally be used for `ActionSheet`.
2. Arrays `buttonTexts`, `buttonStyles` and `handlers` can be of unequal sizes as per requirement.
3. `Actions` can be styled.
4. `Animated` can be specified.
5. Optional `block` can be specified to be executed when presentation finishes.

Usage:

```
popup(caller: self, style: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert,
        title: "Title", message: "Message",
        buttonTexts: ["Destructive", "Cancel", "OK"],
        buttonStyles: [UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, UIAlertActionStyle.cancel],
        handlers: [nil], animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use my Utility class created for Show Alert in Swift4. Its super easy to use just by writing single line of code:

**Show Simple Alert**

```
@IBAction func showDefaultAlert(_ sender: Any) {

  Alert.showAlert(title:"Alert", message:"Default Alert")

}
```

**Demo code link:** https://github.com/smindia1988/EasyAlertInSwift4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present from AppDelegate windows you can use like this

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also the way you can present on top of the View Controller available.

`UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(alertViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)`